# Contact Form Error Msg / JS PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a contact form on anniebest.co.za which has the following code.  It was part of the site before I did some simple changes but has never worked.  Can anyone see the problem here so I can avoid having to completely re-code the form?

This is the error message i get:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@anniebest.flightcentre.ie and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
             $('#contact_form').submit(function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               var form = $(this);
               var name = $("#name").val();
               var email = $("#email").val();
               var text = $("#message").val();
               var dataString = 'name='+name+'&email='+email+'&message='+ text;
                function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
                    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-
    \/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|   
    [!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
    \uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-
    \x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-
    \uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|
    [\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?
     (\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-
     \uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-
     \uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-
    \uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
    \uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-
    z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-  
    \uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-
    \uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
                    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
                };
                if (isValidEmail(email) && (text.length > 20) && (name.length > 1)) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "contact_form/contact_process.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function () {
                            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- the php file -->

<?php
$to = "anniebest8787@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST['email'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$name,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: Apologies for the code, it is not mine!!

Comment: You need to look in your error logs to find out what the 500 server error actually is.

Comment: check your logs or use error reporting if logs are not available for you to use. We also don't know what the form looks for this.

Comment: Also check weather if your service provider enabled the mail function in your cpanel if its not then contact your webmaster

Comment: Add some serverside validation too.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` also what mail gives you back true or false?

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya "whether" not "weather". Heheh, I almost read that as your asking the OP to check for "local weather reports" *lol* Two different animals here. (Sure hope you have a sense of humour).

Comment: Yes @fred people who have common sense will understand what i wrote

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya just trying to help you out with the English language here. "Common sense", I have ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help but we are wasting someone's comment's  rather than giving answer

Comment: ok, nothing else from @Damien24 - I've overstayed the question.